# How to set array name in json using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set an empty array in my constructor like this

```
this.state = {
      formData: [],
}
```

And i'm pushing some data when the user clicks a button like this

```
addFormData() {

    const {formQuestion,formName} = this.props;

    const formRawData = {
      'question': formQuestion,
      'type': this.state.qtype,
    }


    this.state.formData.push(formRawData);


  }
```

With this i'm getting a result like this for the formData

```
[ 
0: {question: "ABC", type: "star"}
1: {question: "ABC", type: "star"}
]
```

How can set the array name (`formName`) to my array like this

```
formName : [ 
    0: {question: "ABC", type: "star"}
    1: {question: "ABC", type: "star"}
]
```

Comment: You mean you want `formData` to be an object (with `formName` as property) and not an array?

Comment: this.state = { formData: {}, }; this.state.formData[formName].push(formRawData);

Answer (score 0):

This `this.state.formData.push(formRawData);` shouldn't be done. You are trying to mutate state. That is what setState is for.

I think you are looking for something like this?

```
this.state = {
      formData: { formName:  []},
}
```

```
addFormData() {

    const {formQuestion,formName} = this.props;

    const formRawData = {
      'question': formQuestion,
      'type': this.state.qtype,
    }

    const formData = {...this.state.formData, formName: [...this.state.formData.formName, formDate]}
    this.setState({formData});


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add data by using `setState` function like:

```
setState({   
    formData:formRawData
})
```